# Proof on surjective functions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I have this assignment:

given a function $f:A\longrightarrow B$ between two sets $A,B$ prove that $f$ is surjective if and only if there exists a function $\psi:B\longrightarrow A$ such that $f\circ\psi=\operatorname{id}_B$.

My thoughts: assume such a $\psi$ exists. Then consider two other functions
$$h,k:B\rightrightarrows\left\{0,1\right\}$$
defined by
$$h(b)=1\text{ if b}\in f(A)$$
and
$$h(b)=0\text{ otherwise}$$
and
$$k(b)=1\text{ for every } b$$
Then $h\circ f=k\circ f$, thus $h\circ f\circ\psi=k\circ f\circ \psi$, thus $h=k$ and so $f(A)=B$.

Now viceversa assume that $f$ is surjective. I have to define $\psi$ and I don't know how. I know that since $f$ is surjective, every element of $B$ has a non-empty inverse image, but how can I get out a function from that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\psi:B\to A$ with $f\circ\psi=\text{id}_{B}$ then for every
$b\in B$ we have $b=f\left(a\right)$ if $a\in A$ is defined by $a:=\psi\left(f\left(b\right)\right)$. This shows that $f$ is surjective.

If conversely $f:A\to B$ is surjective then for every $b\in B$ some
$a_{b}\in A$ exists with $f\left(a_{b}\right)=b$. Then function
$\psi:B\to A$ prescribed by $b\mapsto a_{b}$ will satisfy the condition
$f\circ\psi=\text{id}_{B}$. Needed here is actually the axiom the choice.

Comment: Can I choose the $a_b$ I want? So $\psi$ is not unique?

Comment: Indeed. $\psi$ is not unique in general in this context. If there is uniqueness (special case) then $f$ is bijective.

Comment: Is there no way to avoid AC?

Comment: @ajotatxe No (or more cautious: not that I know of).

Comment: The statement that every surjective function has a right inverse is actually equivalent to AC. I'm looking for a reference right now.

Comment: At the end of my answer, I added a proof that AC follows from every surjective function having a right inverse.

Answer (score 3):

You're making this much too complicated.

If such a $\psi$ exists, to show that $f$ is surjective, you just need to show that for every $b \in B$, there exists $a \in A$ such that $f(a)=b.$  You can define such an $a$ explicitly using $\psi$ and $b.$

For the implication from left to right, note that you'll need to use the axiom of choice.  In fact, that direction is essentially the same as the axiom of choice.

---

By the way, here's how to see that the axiom of choice is actually needed for the above.  Assuming that every surjective function has a right inverse, we'll prove the axiom of choice.  (In fact, they're equivalent; @drhab proved the other direction in his or her answer.)

Suppose that $S$ is a set and that $g$ is a function with domain $S$ such that for every $s$ in $S,$ $g(s)$ is a non-empty set.  We need to show that there is a choice function for $g.$

Let $A=\lbrace \langle s,x \rangle \; |\;  s \in S\text{ and }x \in g(s)\rbrace$.

Let $\pi_1:A \rightarrow S$ be the projection function with domain $A$ defined by setting $\pi_1(\langle s,x\rangle)=s.$ Let $\pi_2$ be the projection function, also with domain $A,$ defined by setting $\pi_2(\langle s,x\rangle)=x.$  Then the definition of $A$ tells us that for any $a \in A,$ we have $$\pi_2(a) \in g(\pi_1(a)).$$

The function $\pi_1:A \rightarrow S$ is surjective. (For any $s \in S,$ $g(s)$ is non-empty; if $x$ is any member of $g(s),$ then $\langle s,x \rangle \in A$ and $\pi_1(\langle s,x\rangle)=s.)$

By our assumption, the surjective function $\pi_1:A \rightarrow S$ must have a right inverse $\psi: S \rightarrow A.$

It follows that $\pi_2 \circ \psi$ is a choice function for $g,$ since for any $s \in S,$ we have:

\begin{align}\pi_2(\psi(s)) \in g(\pi_1(\psi(s))= g(s).\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, @drhab. I didn't want to assume.